# scala | read from file | type mismatch | for-comprehension

Tags: scala, file, for-loop, types

```
val lines:List[String] = Source.fromFile(fullFileName).getLines.toList

for(line <- lines) {
    println(line)
}
```

this code produces the error:

```
"type mismatch; found : Unit required: Array[String]"
```

and underlines "<-" in for

I missunderstand the problem. Where has compiler found Unit, and where is  Array[String] required?

I use eclipse.

Comment: Is there anything around this code which is supposed to have `Array[String]` type? Like `def m(...):Array[String] = { your code here }`?

Comment: paste all your code please. the code you have post works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Victor Moroz was right, there was a function

```
def f(...):Array[String] = {
    val lines:List[String] = Source.fromFile(fullFileName).getLines.toList

    for(line <- lines) {
        println(line)
    }
}
```

This code was for testing "for", I miss the fact that the last statement is a return value. So for(...) {...} has type Unit not Array[String]

thanks